# ECS - task fails to start but container looks fine. Dosn't show error in logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am completely new to AWS and trying this for a cloud assignment. I created a ECS cluster and tried adding both fargate and EC2 tasks with a container. My task fails to start on creation itself and doesn't show any errors in logs. My container is active and doesn't show any errors in details. I am not sure how to debug this. Please , need help.

STOPPED (Task failed to start)

Answer (score 0):

The first step I usually do in this case is to download the docker image from ECR and try and run it on my local machine. If that works, then I SSH into the EC2 host and do the same thing. Usually you'll see *something* go wrong at that point, and you can start debugging from there.